# Why does my program print this string even when i have a while != string

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Hello i made this program that asks the user to input the choices Print,sort1,sort2 or quit

```
usrinpt=0

while usrinpt != "quit":    #if usrinpt == quit then no if statements right?
    usrinpt = input("Enter choice Print, Sort1 (distance), Sort2 (price) or Quit : ")
    usrinpt = usrinpt.lower()
    if usrinpt == "print":
        PrintList(mat)
        pass
    elif usrinpt == "sort1":
        SelectionSortDistorPrice(mat,0)
        PrintList(mat)
        pass
    elif usrinpt == "sort2":
        SelectionSortDistorPrice(mat, 1)
        PrintList(mat)
       pass
    elif usrinpt != "quit"or"sort1"or"sort2":   #why does it print the string even when i enter quit?
        print("please enter a valid choice")
        pass
```

- expected outcome for the choice "quit" is for a the program to stop
- actual outcome is that the program prints " please enter a valid choice" and then quits

how can i fix it to only print that string if a choice not stated is entered?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: where is the indentaion not right? nvm i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif usrinpt not in ["quit","sort1","sort2"]:`